# python Beautifulsoup , помогите вытянуть информацию из тегов

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, теги

всем привет! Нужна помощь по работе супу , мне нужно вытянуть всю информацию которая хранится в тегах a href , без ссылки , просто текст и записать это все в json . Пробовал сам делать все шло коту под хвост( Надеюсь помогут более опытные люди. import requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text




def get_data(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('table', {'style':'padding-top:10px;'})




    for rows in trs.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        ras = rows.find_all('div', class_='left-column')
        ras2 = rows.find_all('div', class_='right-column')
        return  rows







def main():
    groups = {
        'T-691': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=26',
        'Т-717': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=62'
    }
    group = input()
    url = 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id={}'.format(groups[group])
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста замените картинки текстом.

Comment: Я прикрепил код к картинке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цитата из супной доки (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree):

Using a tag name as an attribute will give you only the first tag by that name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
Текст разбираемой html-странички
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

soup.a
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>
```

If you need to get all the  tags, or anything more complicated than the first tag with a certain name, you’ll need to use one of the methods described in Searching the tree, such as find_all():

```
soup.find_all('a')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```